# Php Strings manipulations (Extract first word)

Tags: php, string

I have a paragraph below, that I want from it is the first word of every end of a period.

```
$paragraph="Microsoft is writing down $6.2 billion of the goodwill within its OSD. It's worth noting that at the time of the acquisition, the company recorded $5.3 billion of goodwill assigned to the OSD, bringing its total carrying balance up to $5.9 billion in September of that year. The goodwill in the OSD had climbed up to $6.4 billion by March of this year, so this accounting charge is wiping out the vast majority of that figure.";
```

for example, I can do this.

```
$sentences=explode('.',$paragraph);
print_r( $sentences);
```

and it prints

```
Array ( [0] => Microsoft is writing down $6
        [1] => 2 billion of the goodwill within its OSD 
        [2] => It's worth noting that at the time of the acquisition, the company recorded $5 
        [3] => 3 billion of goodwill assigned to the OSD, bringing its total carrying balance up to $5                            
        [4] => 9 billion in September of that year 
        [5] => The goodwill in the OSD had climbed up to $6 
        [6] => 4 billion by March of this year, so this accounting charge is wiping out the vast majority    of that figure 
        [7] => )
```

however, I was wandering how can one get the first word from every array.
for example how is it  possible to create a function that will get the first word like the example below:

Microsft
2
it's
3
9
The
4

Thanks

Comment: Try `explode(' ',$paragraph)`

Comment: @someGuy, be sure to include the `homework` tag in the future so people can properly answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `explode()` on each sentence, but use a space, instead of a period.

```
$paragraph = "Microsoft is writing down $6.2 billion of the goodwill within its OSD. It's worth noting that at the time of the acquisition, the company recorded $5.3 billion of goodwill assigned to the OSD, bringing its total carrying balance up to $5.9 billion in September of that year. The goodwill in the OSD had climbed up to $6.4 billion by March of this year, so this accounting charge is wiping out the vast majority of that figure.";

$sentences = explode('.', $paragraph);

foreach($sentences as $sentence){
 $words = explode(' ', trim($sentence));
 $first = $words[0];
 echo $first;
}
```

Comment: it would skip some words, I have shared the output.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to `trim()` each sentence. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks, This the trim did the trick, but if I  may ask, what the did the trim function did here.

Comment: It removes spaces from the beginning and ending of each sentence.  It is important because you are exploding the sentences using spaces as separators, and if a separator (space) appears at the beginning, the first word will be an empty word and the one you are looking for would be the second.

Comment: @someGuy, well, the `explode()` was returning " It's worth noting..." for `$sentences[2]`, which returned `$words = Array([0] => "", [1] => "It's", ...)`, while you were expecting `$words[0]` to be "It's". The `trim()` call simply removed the empty array items from the beginning and end.

Comment: @bfrohs I understand now, but now I'm having problems with my function trying to return the first words in an arrayfunction Find_firstword($p){

$sentences = explode('.', $paragraph);

foreach($sentences as $sentence){
 $words = explode(' ', trim ($sentence) );

 $first =$words[0];
 $wordArray[]= $first;
}
 
 
 return $wordArray;     
}
 
 
 
 $test=Find_firstword($paragraph);
 
 
 
 print_r($test);

Comment: @someGuy, you're using `$p` as the function parameter, but trying to explode `$paragraph`. Fix that, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
$paragraph="Microsoft is writing down $6.2 billion of the goodwill within its OSD. It's worth noting that at the time of the acquisition, the company recorded $5.3 billion of goodwill assigned to the OSD, bringing its total carrying balance up to $5.9 billion in September of that year. The goodwill in the OSD had climbed up to $6.4 billion by March of this year, so this accounting charge is wiping out the vast majority of that figure.";

firstWords($paragraph);

function firstWords($paragraph) {
  $sentences = explode('.', $paragraph);

  foreach ($sentences as $sentence) {
   $words = explode(' ', trim($sentence));
   echo $words[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this one, the ouput would be "MicrosoftIt'sThe", but where is the numbers.

Comment: The numbers also will come in the result  ---Microsoft2It's39The4